# Can I redeem SHiFT codes on my computer and play on my PS3?

Tags: borderlands-2

Is it possible to redeem a SHiFT code on a account on PC and log in with the same account on my PS3 and still get the keys?

I seriously don't want to try it out because if I don't get my keys, I might break my CD in rage...

Comment: I assume not, they have different SHIFT codes for PS3 and PC. Don't you have PS3 keys? They usually release a key for each platform

Comment: I highly doubt it, crossplatform anything is a myth.

Comment: Is there such thing as "logging in to PS3 **with the same account** as PC"??? O_O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ben Brocka stated in the comments, the SHIFT codes are console specific.  If you have keys for PC, **they WILL NOT work on PS3.  (and any other combination you can think of between PS3, XBOX360, and PC)**

If you have twitter, try following [Randy Pitchford](https://twitter.com/DuvalMagic), the President of Gearbox Software, OR directly, [Gearbox Software](https://twitter.com/GearboxSoftware) as he will post on average 1 SHIFT Code a week per console for a golden key.

[image]

Example of SHIFT codes posted(retweeted):
[image]

Comment: alternatively, if you use reddit, check out reddit.com/r/borderlands.  They post the weekly shift codes/what day they're for in the header